# gapi.drive.realtime.custom.getModel suddenly does not exist

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

We're using the drive realtime API and this morning [gapi.drive.realtime.custom.getModel](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.custom#gapi.drive.realtime.custom.getModel) no longer exists. Unfortunately, we depend on it, and our app is busted.

Does anyone know a different way to get the model of a custom object?

Update: other sudden changes seem to include:

- `gapi.drive.realtime.custom.isCustomObject` returns false even for custom objects
- `gapi.drive.realtime.custom.getId` is now undefined

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. This issue was caused by a bug which caused our Javascript compiler to inadvertently remove these properties and has now been resolved.

We have updated our tests to run against the compiled API to prevent a recurrence of this type of issue. We also added more testing of custom objects to our manual test procedure.

Answer (score 0):

We have worked around this so far by avoiding the three functions above altogether. We store the model that we get at document creation time and refer to it directly instead of looking up the model from the custom object. Luckily for us we only have one document per app instance so this was relatively easy~